# I have some confusion about Include Guards

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have two file, the first file is called `main.cpp` and that contains the main function, and the second file is called `class.h` and that contains a declaration for a class.
in the same two files I have been included `<iostream>` file, because each file needs that file
file.

What I want from the second file is check if file `iostream` has been already included within the  first file `main.cpp`, does not include it again.

**What I done**

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"
```

---

```
//class.h
#ifndef iostream_H
 #include <iostream>
#endif
```

Is that code right?, and how can I make sure that it does not include the file again ?

Comment: The header itself (more precisely the include guards inside it) takes care of that. You don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"What I want from the second file is check if file iostream has been already included within the first file main.cpp, does not include it again." you don't need to - include whatever files you need - **don't rely on them being included by other files**.

`<iostream>` has its own include guards, so even if it is included multiple times, it's okay.

If both `class.h` and `main.cpp` require `<iostream>` to compile, both should include it.

Comment: `<iostream>` has its own include guards, so even if it is included multiple times, it's okay. Does this rule conform to all of the files that are included ?

Comment: @LionKing yes, but you'll have to add include guards to headers you write yourself.

Comment: @LionKing For standard headers, the standard doesn't say; the implementation is required to do something so that they can be included multiple times without problems.  For your own headers, you have to provide your own include guards.

Answer (score 4):

On top of what [Luchian Grigore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673730/luchian-grigore) has [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792706/1137388).

External include guards (as those in the OP) violate encapsulation because you need to know the internal detail of the header file, namely, the name of the guard.

In addition, those names are not standardized and, hence, external include guards are not portable.

Therefore, do not use external include guards. Add internal include guards to your own header files and be assured that everyone else (including the Standard Library) does the same.

Comment: @Lion King: Hakuna matata ;-) I'm glad it helped.